# Monitoring progress in Parallel.ForEach every minute

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, task-parallel-library

I'm using `Parallel.ForEach` to download 500K URLs and I want to monitor the number of URLs that have been successfully downloaded each minute.

```
        int elapsedMinutes = 0, cnt = 0;
        Parallel.ForEach(list, tuple =>
        {
            var currMinutes = (int) ((DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMinutes);
            lock (Object)
            {
                if (currMinutes > elapsedMinutes)
                {
                    elapsedMinutes = currMinutes;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Extracted {1} urls", DateTime.Now, cnt);
                }
            }

            //download urls ...

            Interlocked.Increment(ref cnt);
        });
```

It looks fine now but the lock statement part seems a bit ugly to me. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of checking the time from each thread on each iteration, I would use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer):

```
int count = 0;

TimeSpan reportPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1);

using (new Timer(
    _ => Console.WriteLine("{0}: Extracted {1} urls", DateTime.Now, count),
    null, reportPeriod, reportPeriod))
{
    Parallel.ForEach(
        list, tuple =>
        {
            //download urls ...

            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        });
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}: Done", DateTime.Now);
```

I have also renamed `cnt` to `count`, those two characters are not worth it to make your code less readable.